# How to properly translate this sentence?

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure

How to properly translate this sentence from English to German?

**"Latest Berlin transit news covering S-Bahn and U-Bahn"**

Specifically having trouble with word "transit". Words "transit" or "transportation" sometimes have different meanings in different countries (like traffic or hint at specific pre-assumed modes of transport). In this sentence it refers to **public transit / mass transportation.**

Comment: *Die neuesten S- und U-Bahn-Nachrichten.*

Comment: Maybe not quite what you're looking for, but German has a very handy acronym, [ÖPNV](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96ffentlicher_Personennahverkehr), for this kind of thing. I found in *Die Zeit* via DWDS: *In der Tat wird die anstehende Reform des „öffentlichen Personennahverkehrs“ (häßlich ÖPNV abgekürzt) kaum Begeisterung wecken, dafür Querelen mit den Bundesländern provozieren und den Wähler verärgern.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some context would be needed. As RDBury suggested: "Die jüngsten/neuesten ÖPNV-Meldungen zu S- und U-Bahn in Berlin." could be fitting (translating transit with ÖPNV), but this is merely a term, not a sentence. If "transit news" refers to delays or line breakdowns/closed stations, one might translate "die neuesten Störungen und Verspätungen" or something like that.

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful!